# Show that $\Phi (n)= n-2^{2k-2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an even perfect number $n = 2^{k-1}(2^k-1)$. Show that $\Phi (n)= n-2^{2k-2}$

so far this is what i have $$ \Phi(n) = \Phi (2^{k-1}(2^k-1))$$ $$ \Phi(2^{k-1}) \Phi(2^k-1)$$ $$2^k-2^{k-1} \Phi(2^k-1)$$ now this is where i am kind of stuck i can't seem to work this part out $$\Phi(2^k-1)$$ because we do not know if $2^k-1$ is prime or composite

Comment: *Hint:* If $n = 2^{k-1}(2^k-1)$ is a perfect number, then $2^k-1$ is a Mersenne Prime!

Comment: It's $\phi$ or $\varphi$, not $\Phi$. Don't use the capital phi letter, because it's often used to denote e.g. cyclotomic polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: $2^{k-1}\left(2^k-1\right)$ is a perfect number ($k\in\Bbb Z^+$) if and only if $2^k-1$ is prime (i.e. [a Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime)).

Proof: We know the identity $$\left(1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{k-1}\right)+\left(1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{k-1}\right)\left(2^k-1\right)=2^k\left(2^k-1\right),$$

so if $2^k-1$ is prime, then $\sigma\left(2^{k-1}\left(2^k-1\right)\right)=2^k\left(2^k-1\right)$ ([divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)), and if $2^k-1$ is composite, then $\sigma\left(2^k-1\right)>2^k\left(2^k-1\right)$. $\square$

$\gcd\left(2^{k-1},2^k-1\right)=1$, so

$$\phi\left(2^{k-1}\left(2^k-1\right)\right)=\phi\left(2^{k-1}\right)\phi\left(2^k-1\right)$$

$$=\left(2^{k-1}-2^{k-2}\right)\left(2^k-2\right)=2^{k-1}\left(2^k-1\right)-2^{2k-2}$$